# How do I properly write an "or" statement in an Nginx location block?

Tags: nginx, configuration, cache, conditional

I'm using Nginx on CentOS 7.  I want to add a cache control header for files that end in a  particular extension or taht contain a "/image/" string in the URL.  I tried this

```
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://scale; # match the name of upstream directive which is defined above
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    if ($request_uri ~* ".(ico|gif|jpe?g|png)$") | ($request_uri ~* "/image/") {
      expires 60d;
      access_log off;
      add_header Pragma public;
      add_header Cache-Control "public";
      break;
    }
  }
```

but upon restarting the server, I'm getting a

```
invalid condition "$request_uri" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/scale.conf:16
```

error.  If I remove " | ($request_uri ~* "/image/")" from the problematic line, all restarts fine, but then I'm unable to match stuff that I want.  How do I write a proper or statement in my configuration file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In nginx, [if is evil](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/). But if you really want to do it that way, here's how you would do it:

`if ($request_uri ~* "($\/image\/.*)|(.*\.(ico|gif|jpe?g|png)$)") {`

Essentially, just combine the regexes.